# Last line on page 1 is picking up formatting of heading at top of page 2

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, formatting, styles

The header on page two, "Lesson Two", is formatted with a style "Header 2". No matter what I do, the last line of the previous page insists on having the same formatting. So if I remove or change the style, both the last line on page 1 and the header on page 2 are affected. I've tried deleting the problem parts and retyping in case there was some hidden code, but that didn't help.

This happens any time there is a page break followed by a new style. It's happening in all of my documents.

I don't know if this makes a difference, but this is DOC file being edited in Word 2010, not a DOCX.

Here's my screencap:

[image: Style problem V2]

Why is this happening?

Comment: Maybe the Header is divided between the 2 pages

Comment: Please be more specific. (1) What version of Microsoft Word are you using? (2) Does this happen every time you have a page break, or only when you have a Heading 2 after a page break? (3) Please redo your screen capture with Show/Hide ¶ (Ctrl+`*`) and Reveal Formatting (Shift+F1), scrolled to show the paragraph formatting. Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question (using the appropriate [microsoft-word-nnnn] tag) to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: I can't repro in Word 2013, but I'm not certain either that this is specific to 2010 or the .DOC file format. What happens if you use a `Section Break (Next Page)` break?

Comment: Good news - That works as a workaround. I'm still mystified by the original problem but this helps.  Thanks, Twisty!

Comment: It's because the page break and the heading proper are technically in the same paragraph. You can tell, because the dotted 'Page Break' line extends all the way across the page and there's no ¶ at the end of it. To fix without inserting a section break, just click before the L of 'Lesson' and press Enter.